# global db4o database for multiple activities

Tags: java, db4o

I am working on a design project and I am needing some guidance with db4o since it is the first time I have worked with it.  In the project we have an Android app that has multiple activities and all of which use the same database.  After reading and googling the opening and closing of these databases is hard on the processor so opening and closing within each activity is unreasonable.

How do I open and close a db4o database that needs to be used throughout the applications life?  When/where do I call the open and close?

edit: Will I need an exit/close button in the app for when to call the close database method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if this works, since my Android knowledge is limited.

**Custom Application Object**
You can register your custom application object. See [here](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android#). This object can life cycle callbacks, which are called when your App is started or terminated. It stays alive across activities.

So, create your own application which extends android.app.Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private volatile ObjectContainer container;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // the application object is a regular Android context,
        // So you can get the required info`
        this.container = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(...)
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        // if something was not finished, better rollback
        container.rollback();
        container.close();
    }

    public ObjectContainer database(){
        return container;
    }

}
```

Then register that object with:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" 
       android:name="my.packages.MyApplication">
```

Then you can the instance of your any time in your activities with:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
ObjectContainer container = app.database();
```

**Static-Singleton**

Another solution can be a classic 'static' singleton. As long as your application is running, the same instance of a class is loaded. So it will keep the container alive.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried to use the way posted and from the little tutorial but I ended up trying to use the singleton, which I have another post with because I am having trouble with that too! :(